# Why is \glueexpr used in etoolbox's \deflength instead of \dimexpr

Tags: calculations, lengths, etoolbox

Consider the following snippet from `etoolbox`:

```
\newrobustcmd*{\deflength}[2]{%
  \ifundef{#1}
    {\etb@noglobal\etb@err@nolen{#1}}%
    {#1\glueexpr#2\relax}}
```

Maybe I do not understand the differences between `\numexpr`, `\dimexpr`, `\glueexpr` and `\muglueexpr` (e-TeX expressions), but I suspected the use of `\dimexpr` in the definition
of `\deflength` just like `\numexpr` is used in the definition of `\defcounter`
Can someone explain the difference?

Comment: latex lengths are skips (glue) not dimens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should answer the question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength{\mylenA}
\newlength{\mylenB}
\begin{document}

\mylenA=5pt plus 2pt
\showthe\mylenA % \mylenA = 5pt plus 2pt

\setlength{\mylenB}{\mylenA}
\showthe\mylenB % \mylenB = 5pt plus 2pt

\setlength{\mylenB}{\dimexpr\mylenA}
\showthe\mylenB % \mylenB = 5pt (no glue)

\setlength{\mylenB}{\glueexpr\mylenA}
\showthe\mylenB % \mylenB = 5pt plus 2pt

\end{document}
```

The `.log` outputs:

```
> 5.0pt plus 2.0pt.
l.7 \showthe\mylenA


> 5.0pt plus 2.0pt.
l.10 \showthe\mylenB


> 5.0pt.
l.13 \showthe\mylenB


> 5.0pt plus 2.0pt.
l.16 \showthe\mylenB
```

If you set a length using `\dimexpr<len>` you lose any glue. Using `\glueexpr<len>` the glue is kept.

Comment: By `<len>` I refer to a length macro, not an actual length.

Comment: The important thing you don't mention is that latex's `\newlength` defines a skip register not a dimen register. that is it is based on `\newskip` not `\newdimen`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. As you mentioned, the main reason must be that `\newlength` defines a skip instead of a dimen.