# How do prevent blank line between theorem and run-in heading

Tags: sectioning, theorems

I'm having some trouble combining my custom section style with a theorem environment. How can I prevent the theorem from leaving the first line of the section blank? Here is my code and the current output.

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\mysection{m}{
    \@startsection
        {paragraph}{2}{\z@}
        {3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}
        {\z@}
        {\normalfont\normalsize}*
        {\makebox[0pt][r]{(#1)\hspace\labelsep}}
}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[name=Theorema]{theorem}

\begin{document}
\mysection{A}
Sed ornare non felis in hendrerit. Maecenas eros est, consequat ac tellus non, aliquam ultrices dui.

\mysection{B}
\begin{theorem}
    Etiam ipsum erat, tristique sit amet ante non, porta iaculis odio. Ut tempus suscipit urna, in semper arcu mollis nec
    \[
        1 + 1 = 2.
    \]
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem} $1 \ne 0$.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
\dots
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution.

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
%\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\mysection{m}{
    \@startsection
        {paragraph}{2}{\z@}
        {3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}
        {\z@}
        {\normalfont\normalsize}*
        {\makebox[0pt][r]{(#1)\hspace\labelsep}}
}
\newcommand{\compress}{@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[name=Theorema]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\mysection{A}
Sed ornare non felis in hendrerit. Maecenas eros est, consequat ac tellus non, aliquam ultrices dui.

\mysection{B}\leavevmode \vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \topsep\relax}
\begin{theorem}
    Etiam ipsum erat, tristique sit amet ante non, porta iaculis odio. Ut tempus suscipit urna, in semper arcu mollis nec
    \[
        1 + 1 = 2.
    \]
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem} $1 \ne 0$.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
\dots
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

*Unrelated*: since you babel-latin, maybe you should replace the end-of-proof symbol with Q.E.D.  (or even E.O.Δ.) ;O)
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Could you please also explain how/why this works? I don't really understand glue stretching, but is this robust enough to handle any stretching that might occur between the heading and the theorem?

Comment: Update: It works on the first page of my document, but theorems on another page become misaligned because there is too much negative space. I'll try to produce an example

Comment: Changing it to `\leavevmode \vspace*{-\baselineskip - \topsep}` works for now. I have no idea why.

Comment: That's because `amsthm`inserts a `\baselineskip` before (and after) a theorem environment, plus a `\thmpreskip` (and `\thmpostskip` afterwards), which by default is set to `\topsep`.

Comment: Ok, that explains why we need to subtract the two values. But I had to remove `\dimexpr` from your answer to make it work. Also, why do we need the starred variant of `\vspace`?

Comment: The starred variant is to force the vertical skip, even if we're not in horizontal mode. But it's strange it doesn't work for you with `\dimexpr`; which is a command from `etex`. Maybe you have an old installation?

Comment: My installation is up to date. I found a clue [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238463/239612): "If you set a length using `\dimexpr<len>` you lose any glue. Using `\glueexpr<len>` the glue is kept.". I suppose omitting the command alltogether also preserves any glue.

Comment: Probably. Or maybe you load `calc` for your document? Anyway, you can also use `\glueexpr`.I must say I didn't think of this problem when I posted.

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior without any other packages loaded.